# JAVA regex to find string

Tags: java, regex

i have a string like this:

```
font-size:36pt;color:#ffffff;background-color:#ff0000;font-family:Times New Roman;
```

How can I get the value of the color and the value of background-color?

color:#ffffff;

background-color:#ff0000;

i have tried the following code but the result is not my expected.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^.*(color:|background-color:).*;$");
```

The result will display:

```
font-size:36pt; color:#ffffff; background-color:#ff0000; font-family:Times New Roman;
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: *but seems not work* - pretty vague, what did you do with the pattern after this?  [Please add a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Maybe `string.split(";").filter(s -> s.contains("color")` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have multiple matches in a string, don't assert `^` and `$` because if those matches, then the whole string matches, which means that you can't match it again.

Also, use a lazy quantifier like `*?`. This will stop matching as soon as it finds some string that matches the pattern after it.

This is the regex you should use:

```
(color:|background-color:)(.*?);
```

Group 1 is either `color:` or `background-color:`, group 2 is the color code.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uc8jRS/1)

Comment: As a side question (and I'm really trying to learn!), lazy quantifiers seem to make the regex less efficient (at least by [regex101.com](regex101.com) calculations). Do you still think it should be used?

Comment: @GalAbra I found this article about performance: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/greedy-lazy-performance

Answer (score 1):

To do this you should use the `(?!abc)` expression in regex. This finds a match but doesn't select it. After that you can simply select the hexcode, like this:

```
String s = "font-size:36pt;color:#ffffff;background-color:#ff0000;font-family:Times New Roman";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?!color:)#.{6}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: I think, also the color part should be a group - then the order of color/background-color in the input does not matter (you can use the result to see which match it is)

Answer (score 1):

No need to describe the whole input, only the relevant part(s) that you're looking to extract.

The regex `color:(#[\\w\\d]+);` does the trick for me:

```
String input = "font-size:36pt;color:#ffffff;background-color:#ff0000;font-family:Times New Roman;";
String regex = "color:(#[\\w\\d]+);";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Notice that `m.group(1)` returns the matching group which is **inside the parenthesis** in the regex. So the regex actually matches the whole `color:#ffffff;` and `color:#ff0000;` parts, but the print only handles the number itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("color\\s*:\\s*([^;]+)\\s*;\\s*background-color\\s*:\\s*([^;]+)\\s*;");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("font-size:36pt; color:#ffffff; background-color:#ff0000; font-family:Times New Roman;");
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("color:" + matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println("background-color:" + matcher.group(2));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a CSS parser like [ph-css](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.helger/ph-css/6.1.1)

```
String input = "font-size:36pt; color:#ffffff; background-color:#ff0000; font-family:Times New Roman;";
final CSSDeclarationList cssPropertyList = 
    CSSReaderDeclarationList.readFromString(input, ECSSVersion.CSS30);
    System.out.println(cssPropertyList.get(1).getProperty() + " , "
            + cssPropertyList.get(1).getExpressionAsCSSString());
    System.out.println(cssPropertyList.get(2).getProperty() + " , "
            + cssPropertyList.get(2).getExpressionAsCSSString());
```

Prints:

```
color , #ffffff
background-color , #ff0000
```

Find more about [ph-css on github](https://github.com/phax/ph-css)